# Make multiple JLabel in one Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, jlabel

In Netbeans:
I have add 4 JLabel in one pane of JFrame:

[image]

I have create an array of JLabel:

```
private JLabel[] myLab = new JLabel[]{};
```

Please, I want to now, it's possible to make this `JLabel`s (`jLabel1`, `jLabel2`, `jLabel3`, `jLabel4`) in one array, for call in program with `MyLab[0], MyLab[ 1], MyLab[2], MyLab[3]`?

Comment: Yes, probably better to use an `ArrayList` though.  Can you show us what code you have attempted?  Do you know what a `for` loop is?

Answer (score 2):

**Update <sup>(as [markspace suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468117/make-multiple-jlabel-in-one-array-java/52468225#comment91878248_52468225))</sup> :**

The correct syntax to create the array is,

```
private JLabel[] myLab2 = new JLabel[4];
```

because you need an array with a length of 4 to store 4 elements in the array. By using `new JLabel[]{}` you are creating an array with a length of 0.

---

You can't edit the generated codes in NetBeans. So assign the `jLable`s to the array in the constructor after the `initComponents();` statement.

```
myLab[0] = jLabel1;
myLab[1] = jLabel2;
myLab[2] = jLabel3;
myLab[3] = jLabel4;
```

Now refer `jLable1` as `myLab[0]`.

Comment: Also the OP's example of creating an array is incorrect.  `private JLabel[] myLab2 = new JLabel[4];` is the correct syntax.